# Compile time subclass byte-offset with virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++17, sfinae

Is it possible to compute, **at compile time**, the byte offset of a virtual base in an inheritance hierarchy?

Example -

```
class A {};
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public virtual A {};
class D : public virtual B, public virtual C {};
```

I would like to compute the byte offset of instance of `B`, `C`, and `D` w.r.t. `A` **at compile time** i.e. without using any *real* instance of either of these classes.

From what I have read so far online, compilers implement the logic (used by static_cast and dynamic_cast) with help of virtual tables and since there are no *true* instance of any of these classes there is no virtual table to piggyback on. But hoping there is some template magic that could make this work.

Purpose - I am attempting to get this [Custom RTTI](https://kahncode.com/2019/09/24/c-tricks-fast-rtti-and-dynamic-cast/) implementation working with virtual inheritance.

Comment: @S.M.: With Respect To.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to compute, at compile time, the byte offset of a virtual base in an inheritance hierarchy?

No, because it's different for different object instances. It is not a property of the class.

Let's look at your example. `B` has a virtual base class `A`. So `B` has to have some byte offset to an `A`. The same is true for `C`.

However, `D` inherits a virtual `A` through both `B` and `C`. The whole point of `virtual` inheritance is that, if you inherit the same base class, then all of the paths to reach that base class will refer to the *same subobject* of the dynamic type. So `D` only has a single instance of `A`.

But where is it? The offsets that `B` and `C` use cannot *both* be correct. Unless... the offset *itself* is stored in the vtable.

Which is (basically) how virtual inheritance works. When you create a `D`, it is the `D` which is responsible for assigning where all of the `virtual`ly inherited objects go. Those offsets will be different from when you create an object whose dynamic type is `B` or `C`.

There's no way to do what you're trying to do. Not without actually creating instances of objects. While C++20 does allow you to create instances of virtual types at compile time (so long as they have viable `constexpr` constructors, so you can't do it with everything), you still can't do what you need. If you have pointers to two different types, to compute a byte offset between them, you have to  `reinterpret_cast` those pointers into integers or `unsigned char*`s. And `reinterpret_cast` is forbidden at compile-time (and `bit_cast` isn't `constexpr` when given a pointer type or a type that contains a pointer).

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation. As per your comment, `D`'s vtable has the offset where `B` and `C` are stored. Same way `B` and `C` also knows where `A` is stored. `A` offset in '`B` (or `C`) might not be the same as in `D` but the offset is still a _constant_ per type - it cannot be per instance because there's only one vtable per type. The compiler is computing these offsets and updating the corresponding type's vtable. So, is there no way to get the compiler to reveal these values at compile time?

Comment: @Shahji: "*it cannot be per instance because there's only one vtable per type*" The offset is *stored in the vtable*. The dynamic type of the class is the one that puts the offset there. `B`  and `C` will look for the offset in that vtable. That's what allows `B` and `C` to reference the same `A` when they're in a `D`. The offset cannot be "a constant per type"; it has to be determined based on the dynamic type being used. If you create a `B`, that `B` will use a different offset from the `B` inside of a `D`.